# Why was the bounty not awarded to me?

Tags: support, answers, bounty

First I answered [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143999/on-forecasting-the-mean-squared-error-and-realized-volatility) question on March 30 (the same day as the question was posted). Later I got two upvotes.

Then a bounty was started on that question some time in mid-April. I received two upvotes during the bounty period (April 11 and April 14). 
(I am not 100% sure, but I think both April 11 and April 14 fall within the bounty period; how can I check what period the bounty was on?)

My answer was never accepted. There was only one other answer that got only one upvote in total and was not accepted.

I was hoping to get half of the bounty following the [bounty rules](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

-- but that did not happen.

**Question:** What could be the reason I did not get (half of) the bounty?

Comment: "Created after the bounty started"

Comment: @whuber, Oh, I see. Thank you!

Comment: @RichardHardy, maybe you could post an answer to your own question, so it would be highlighted for future users having the same question. Tks.

Answer (score 9):

As @whuber correctly pointed out, my answer was not *created after the bounty started*. Therefore, I did not get half the bounty when it expired. Puzzle solved.